# How to keep a pressed state of a button in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have an app which contains different three activities with recyclerViews.
Every cell contains a star button which is grey.
When user licks the button it becomes yellow.

```
holder.starBtn.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity,android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on));
```

I describe the scenario:

- user is on activity2 and he presses three buttons and they become yellow.
- user moves from activity2 to activity3 and moves back from activity3 to 
  activity2. the pressed buttons are still yellow.
- but when user moves from activity2 to activity1 and back to activity2 the 
  pressed are again grey.

Question is how can i keep the state of the pressed buttons? how can i keep them yellow.
and why the state keep only when user moving forward and not backward?

The only idea i have is to save the positions of the pressed buttons in a sqlite database but is there another way in android to keep the state of the pressed buttons in recyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is either you store the states in either the database or on a Singleton. In that approach you could store the list datasource where it can persist through activity changes.